# Adding the Ajax Control Toolkit to a SharePoint project

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajax-control-tookit

I am unable to get the List Search Extender from the Ajax Control Toolkit to work correctly. After inserting my WebPart to the page, I get the error: "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I followed the installation instructions for Visual Studio 2010 as [found here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/). I see the AjaxControlToolkit listed in the references section of my solution and I have registered the assembly as shown in my code below.

*EDIT: Additionally, the assembly shows up in the GAC and I added a screenshot of the assemblies in my project package and the corresponding safe control in the Web.config

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>

<asp:ListBox ID="VendorSelector" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:ListSearchExtender id="LSE" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="VendorSelector"
  PromptText="Type to search"
  PromptCssClass="ListSearchExtenderPrompt"
  PromptPosition="Top"
  AutoResetTimeout="0"
  QueryPattern="Contains"
  IsSorted="true"/>
```

[image: GAC]

[image: Package]

[image: WebConfig]

Comment: Is the assembly in the GAC? If so, you need to use the full 4 part assembly name (the one with the PublicKeyToken and stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the version and public key of the assembly in my Register statement.  No more runtime errors.

Comment: I should also note that beware when adding assemblies to the project using that interface - if any other solutions rely on that assembly and you retract your solution, it will pull out that assembly from the GAC and break the other solutions.

Comment: also when adding any dll to the gac allway do an iis reset!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the version of the AJAX toolkit you are using is incorrect. I had this issue and after downloading and installing the correct version for my target sharepoint installation, and it worked. Hope this helps.